# How can I prevent an executable from restarting my computer?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

Question is simple: I have an executable on my computer (running windows 7 Professional) that wants to restart my pc to install updates every single day. Unfortunately I can't remove it entirely, so I'm wondering if there's any way to leave it running but somehow revoke its permission to restart my pc.

More info: Looking at the event viewer, it says "exe has initiated the restart of computer on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM"

Comment: I don't think so. If it was Linux, then maybe you could... :D

Comment: An executable can't restart your pc without your permission.  You cannot prevent that permission from being requested, although, you in theory you could grant that permission always automatically.

Comment: tiny bit of a horrible hack would be to keep notepad open. Seems to prevent reboots most of the time.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not at my pc when this happens. I'll add more info to the question.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I can't see that working here as I always have tons of programs open when it happens! Although I will give it a try.

Comment: @Mansfield - Whats the program.  You can't prevent a `NT Authority` from doing squat.

Comment: @Ramhound it's patching software. It used to install updates and restart once a week which was fine...but now it wants to every day which I think is excessive.

Comment: If the patching application requires a reboot to finish its work, it might not be the best idea to prevent it from doing that.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't want to get into exactly what software it is - I understand if you can't help me further as a result. Thanks for your assistance anyway!

Comment: @Mansfield: notepad's save dialogue has some wierd property that prevents a reboot in most cases. Its one of those little mysterious tricks I picked up from random people on the internet. Its always worked for me, so.. ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the software has no options to change the frequency of reboots, then the only means would be to create a recurring task of a batch file running `shutdown /a` and hope that it runs whenever the exe calls for a reboot.

Ultimately, I'd get rid of a software that I can't control. Most people would consider software that "patches stuff" and reboots every day malware.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention this is a work computer, it's the network's patch distribution software so it's definitely not malware.

Comment: In that case I would talk to someone in the IT department and describe this to them. I'm sure they have these patches on a schedule and can look into why yours is so frequent. It might be a simple group policy issue.